# Accidentally Deleted Voice-to-Text app for Samsung Galaxy SIII

Tags: voice-recognition

I was running out of memory on my phone, and so went through all my apps and deleted those I didn't use to create more room....apparently, by doing so, I deleted the app that lets me voice-to-text on text messages or even search by voice in google chrome.

Can someone help me fix this without resetting my phone to factory settings???

Comment: Is your device rooted? if so, restoring it will be more difficult, and a factory reset will not help. If it isn't rooted, and you did remove it, than it can be restored from the play store, or you may have just disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

Not to wake an old thread but I was looking for the solution to this same problem and wasn't finding a solution. I had disabled my Google  app , turning it back on fixed my issue. Settings,applications,all and find "google app"

Answer (score 0):

If anything like this happens, just search online for the apk `eg. Samsung default Voice-to-Text apk download`. But here are the links: [Install from play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts) Sign into your google account that you use on your phone/tablet and then click on install

[APK Download](http://www67.zippyshare.com/v/91666662/file.html)
Not reccommended, use the first one becuase its easier. But if you have to use this one: Download it on your Android and then open it, accept 'Unknown Sources' and you're done)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that I had disabled *Google App*. As soon as I enabled the App, the microphone icon started appearing in my keyboard. Try it, maybe it's the same case.